# How to send attatchments through webservice using iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, web-services, ios4, attachment

In My application i have to send a file(audio,image,text and vedio etc..) to server using webservice.
Here i am sending bytes to application using base64binary string. But here data is corrupted. Is there any way to sending base64binary to service.

Or is there any way to send attachments to service or copy the file into server.

Please any one can help me.

Thanks in advance.

-(NSMutableURLRequest *) SaveAttachments:(NSData *)data name:(NSString *)name fileType:(NSString *)type {

```
[self setUserCredentials];

NSString *strsdf = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *sdf=@"lll.jpg";
NSString *strt = [Base64 encode:data];
//NSLog(@"strt %@",strt);

NSString *soapMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\
                     <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap12=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">\
                     <soap12:Body>\
                     <InsertAttachmentint xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\
                     <Filename>%@</Filename>\
                     <FileType>%@</FileType>\
                     <FileContentint>%@</FileContentint>\
                     </InsertAttachmentint>\
                     </soap12:Body>\
                     </soap12:Envelope>",sdf,type,strsdf];
```

This is the code.
Here strsdf is binary

Comment: Please show the code snippet that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a loot at http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

This wrapper makes it MUCH easier to send and receive data with iOS.